# Sum of rational cubes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

In Hardy & Wright "An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers" there are two theorems:

> Theorem 233: There are positive rationals which are not sums of two non-negative rational cubes.

---

> Theorem 234: Any positive rational is the sum of three positive rational cubes.

The first one is proven by providing a counterexample - the number $3 \in \mathbb Q$, the second one is constructively proven using elementary number theory.

Now I wondered, can we classify the rationals $r  \in \mathbb Q$ that satisfy theorem $233$ - the rationals that are *not* sums of one or two (but three) positive cubes?

Comment: Since Theorem 233 refers to non-negative cubes, you intend: not sums of 1 or 2 positive cubes, correct?

Comment: You're right, thanks for noticing!

Comment: Theorem 234 might be Reyley's theorem (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1245065)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have run into a problem of probable not total solution until the end of times. Actually, you want to know for which rational numbers $A$ (you can assume without loss of generality that $A$ is positive integer)   the equation $X ^ 3 + Y ^ 3 = AZ ^ 3$ has rational solutions.

This equation represents an elliptic curve from which the first one who studied it closely was the Norwegian mathematician E. S. Selmer (1920-2006) who calculated (without computers!) a very laborious table  from $1$ to $166$ in which the integers representable by this equation          ($6,7,9,37,61,….$) appear  and in which implicitly the integers that do not appear are those that cannot be represented ($10,11,21,54,55,56,…..$).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems elliptic curves pop up everywhere:) Do you have a reference where you found those numbers?

Comment: Yes: E. S. Selmer, The diophantine equation $ax^3+by^3+cz^3=0$, Acta Math. (Stockh.) $\mathbf{85}$ , p.203-362.

Comment: Great, thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. These curves have been well studied. In the tables you will also find the ranges corresponding to each case of $ A $ what for Selmer must have been a very arduous job. It is also shown (after Selmer) that these curves (defined over an extension of rationals) have complex multiplication by $\sqrt{-3}$ (maybe you do not know this notion and I tell you with all purpose to see if you dare to know this topic later).

Comment: Naturally excluding cube $A$, the updated version where $X^3+Y^3 = AZ^3$ **has** a solution is A = {2, 6, 7, 9, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 22, 26, 28, 30, 31, 33, 34, 35, 37,...} or https://oeis.org/A020897 and when it **has no** solution is A = {3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 14, 18, 21, 23, 24, 25, 29, 32, 36,...} or https://oeis.org/A185345.

Comment: Not only for $A=2$ but $X^3+Y^3=Z^3$ also have "solution" but the corresponding curves have no infinitely many points because the obvious "solutions" $(1,1,1)$ and $(1,0,1)$ are of torsion. All the other curves are torsion-free and have an infinity of points.
(as historic reference, Legendre thought that for $A=6$ the curve have no points, integers of course). Sorry for bad English without Google translator